# Magento EcomDev PHPUnit - Admin Session Error on Install

Tags: unit-testing, magento, phpunit

After installing [this package](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/) and running the initial phpunit command, I get failures for every method in the `EcomDev_PHPUnitTest_Test_Helper_Session` class, and one error.

There error is:

```
1) EcomDev_PHPUnitTest_Test_Helper_Session::testAdminSessionAllRights Exception: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 10: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

If I comment out the 3 tests in this class (t`estAdminSessionAllRights, testAdminSessionOnlyCatalog, testAdminSessionOnlyCatalogProduct`) then everything passes correctly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this.  One of my config XML files was commented out, however, was still registered and therefore was attempting to be parsed.  It didn't have any opening XML tags (or any code / tags at all) so the parser threw an error.